# how to preserve IFrame functionality?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have an IFrame with a div around it. I am trying to track the clicks on the div. This works. The only problem is that the Iframe functionality does not work anymore? How can I make this work? Is it possible?

html

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head id="Head1" runat="server"> 
    <title></title> 
    <style> 
        #mydiv 
        { 
            height: 300px; 
            width: 300px; 
            border: 1px solid; 
        } 

        #clickerDiv  
        { 
            height: 300px; 
            position: absolute; 
            width: 300px; 
            z-index:222;
        } 
    </style> 
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script>

        $(function () {
            var clicks = 0;
            $('#mydiv').bind('click', function (e) {
                clicks++;
                $("#numberclicks").html(clicks);
                return true;
            });
        }); 

    </script> 
</head> 
<body> 
    <form id="form1" runat="server"> 
    <div> 
        <span id="numberclicks">0</span> 
        <div id="mydiv"> 
            <div id="clickerDiv">
              </div> 
            <iframe id="myframe" src="http://www.jquery.com" width="300" height="300" /> 

        </div> 
    </div> 
    </form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: "Iframe functionality"? Please explain.

Comment: Is there a need for your return statement?  Also e isn't being used ;p

Comment: @Rob W, the containing site in the Iframe does not work anymore, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Your div, which is a peer of the iframe and has an explicitly-high z-order, is covering up the iframe. Did you want the div to be transparent?

I'm curious what this is for - it looks like a clickjacking implementation.

Comment: you think I should remove the z-index? I just want to track when the user clicks a Facebook like button. The FB button is implemented as an iframe.

Comment: can you set the opacity of the covering div to 0?

Comment: Wait, you probably want the click to actually go to the like button, right? You don't want to block it, you just want to notice it.

Comment: such magic does not exist... the div is on a different document. only one document can catch the click

Comment: @Bruce it is not clickjacking:)